# Gta 5 script error with godmode

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a small script for gta 5 using menya baes, and I was wondering if someone could help me out. the current problem I am facing is when I enable godmode I am not able to turn it off. I am  aware that the mistake is that the game is waiting for me to not be a human, however I cannot find a working toggle because  `void SET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(Player player, BOOL toggle)` gives me an error while compiling. anyway thanks for the help in advance, here is the rest of the code

```
void Player()

{
    // Initialise local variables here:
    bool BoolOff = 0; bool BoolOn = 0; bool sample_invisible = 0; bool model_changer = 0;


// Options' text here:
AddTitle("Self Options");
AddLocal("Invincibility", GET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_ID()), BoolOn, BoolOff);
AddLocal("Invisible", !IS_ENTITY_VISIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID()), sample_invisible, sample_invisible);
AddOption("Model Changer", model_changer);




// Options' code here:
if (BoolOn)
{
     SET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_ID(), BOOL )toggle);



    return; // Either use return; to exit to the switch if you don't have code below that you want executed.
}
if (sample_invisible) {
    if (IS_ENTITY_VISIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID())) SET_ENTITY_VISIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID(), 0);
    else SET_ENTITY_VISIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID(), 1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `SET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_ID(), BOOL )toggle);` isn't valid C++, unless there's some very strange macro stuff going on.

Answer (score -2):

```
bool GodBoolOn = 0;
bool GodBoolOff = 0;

AddLocal("God Mode", GET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_ID()), GodBoolOn, GodBoolOff);


        if (GodBoolOn)
    {
         SET_ENTITY_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID(), TRUE);
         return;
    }
    else if (GodBoolOff)
    {
         SET_ENTITY_INVINCIBLE(PLAYER_PED_ID(), FALSE);
         return;
    }
```

No problem ;)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.